# Jquery returned div with class

Tags: jquery

I have this page which has a javascript loaded once the page is loaded succesfully:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //I have this triggering event
    $(".myinput").click(function() { /*code here*/
    });
    $.post("load/post.php", {
        message: message,
        poster: <? php echo json_encode($_SESSION['id']); ?>,
        id: <? php echo json_encode($_SESSION['id']); ?>
    }, function(result) {
        $(html).append(result);
    });
});
```

The result contains an input with the same class as the click function, `class=myinput` but the click event won't trigger after `$.post` appends it's content to the html... how can I make it fire for that function too?
Thank you.

Comment: I sense some big security issues in trusting user to send ajax with poster id.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `on` (or `live` if an older version of jQuery):

```
$(".myinput").on("click", function(){
    /*code here*/
  });
```

You may need to do something like this:

```
 $('#parent').on("click", ".myinput", function() {
    /*code here*/
 });
```

More information: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

ok, the issue here is that when you set an event handler, jquery expected the HTML was set before the handler. To allow jquery to set handler for HTML (dom objects) that does not exist then you should use something like:

```
$('body').on('click', '.myinput', function(){
/*code here*/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the code to be execute on click with [`$.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) (or [`$.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), if using ancient versions of jQuery):

```
$.on("click", ".myinput", null, function(){
    /*code here*/
});
```

That's because `$(<your expression here>)` returns a list of the elements currently in the DOM that matches your search.